# instantiating object returns an error after export default in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase-admin

I have a models dir:

```
models/
-- index.ts
-- basemodel.ts
-- auth.ts
-- validator.ts
```

of all the models only **auth.ts inherits basemodel**

**models/index.ts**

```
export { default as BaseModel } from './basemodel.ts';
export { default as Auth } from './auth.ts';
export { default as Validator } from './validator.ts';
```

**models/basemodel.ts**

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';

export default abstract class BaseModel {
  private _collection: firestore.Firestore;

  get collection(): firestore.Firestore {
    return this._collection
  }

  constructor() {
    this._collection = firestore().collection(
      this.constructor.name.toLowerCase()
    )
  }


  //... more codes
}
```

**models/auth.ts**

```
import { BaseModel } from '.';

export default new (class Auth extends BaseModel)()
```

now I created a file in **middleware/input-validator.ts**

```
import * as joi from 'joi';
import { Validator } from '../models';

export default (schema) => (req, res, next) => {
  const result = new Validator(schema,  req.body, //... callback codes removed)

  //.. if result true then next() else throw response err
}
```

now when I try to serve the **function**(`I am using firebase function with TS`)

it returns an error:

```
Cannot read property 'firestore' of undefined
```

Now I tried to remove the **new** inside the **auth.ts** as shown below:

**models/auth.ts**

```
import { BaseModel } from '.';

export default class Auth extends BaseModel {};
```

and tried to `serve` and it worked;

now my question is, how did it occur?

I tried to check the stack trace but it points out the `base model` being the `firestore to be undefined`;

is this a gotcha in modules or other stuff in typescript or es6 in general(or the lack of it)?

also here's my `tsconfig`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**EDIT**:

I forgot to add, the service that the auth is being called to.

**services/auth-service.ts**

```
import { Auth } from '../models';

export default class AuthService {
   constructor() { 
     this.model = Auth;
   }
}
```

now its being using in a post

```
import * as AuthService from './services';

app.post("/login", (req, res) => { 
 const { email, password } = req.body;

 new AuthService().login(email, password)

 //.. create token and respond with token
})
```

Comment: Where's the import of `Auth`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder.  It has been used in a class named `AuthService`, which in turn is used for logging in

Comment: You've said changing what `auth.ts` exports changes the problem. So we need to see the code that *imports* it to know how it's being used.

Answer (score 0):

Following in not a valid import for the Admin SDK.

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';
```

It has to be:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

admin.initializeApp();
const firestore = admin.firestore();
```

See [Import only used bits from firebase-admin when using Typescript in Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57391458/import-only-used-bits-from-firebase-admin-when-using-typescript-in-cloud-functio)